# MySQL Is Ordering All Rows Except One

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to retrieve project numbers from a database in ascending order.

The rows look something like this:

```
-- project number --
       1199.7
       1053.2
       1020
       1023-D
       1023-C
       1023-B
       50
       34.3T
       870-W
```

Here is my query for retrieving and sorting the data:

```
$this->db->select('Project');
$this->db->from('`active_projects`');
$this->db->order_by('Project + 0, Project');
```

Output for part of the table:

[image]

My question is, why is 127 stuck in the middle and not at the top? I'm thinking that it is looking at it the same as 1270 just without the appending 0 but I'm not sure. Can anybody help me out in fixing it?

Comment: Do a search for "mysql natural order", there are a few solutions

Answer (score 2):

Because your data type is string and ordered in alphabet order.

Use `order_by('cast(Project as UNSIGNED), Project');`

Comment: So, how would I fix it?

Comment: Same output as before.

Comment: @Nik, try `UNSIGNED` instead of `decimal`

Comment: Just updated to using `UNSIGNED`, everything is in correct order except the 127. Not sure why it won't move..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the natsort() function from php.

```
$array = $result_from_query;

$sorted_array = natsort($array);
```

Now just return the sorted array.